# create alert function in all view controllers - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to declare a function for showing alerts in my app. To avoid repeating work, i'm trying to use same function for all my app. I tried to do that by creating a class with function showNotification. but when i create an object of that class and call the method, nothing happens. How can i do that?

```
class SharedPropertiesAndMetods : UIViewController {

    func showNotification(title: String, message: String)
    {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "تائید", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: Add this method as extension of UIViewController

Comment: @HosAp there are 4 answers. none of them is helpful?

Comment: @GaneshKumar yes, adding as extension was a good idea

Comment: @GaneshKumar yes, sorry i didn't notice that. If you agree, Luca's answer is more comprehensive. thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is to create a 'generic' view controller that do the job and than inherit from it:

**1. If you want to display alert each time view did appear:**

```
class GenericViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - View lifecycle -

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        if let notification = self.shouldDisplayAlertNotification() {
            self.showNotification(notification)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Internal methods -

    func shouldDisplayAlertNotification() -> AlertNotification? {
        return nil
    }

    // MARK: - Private methods -

    private func showNotification(_ alertNotification: AlertNotification) {
    }

}

class MyController: GenericViewController {

    override func shouldDisplayAlertNotification() -> AlertNotification? {
        return AlertNotification(title: "Title", message: "Message")
    }

}
```

Where AlertNotification is your custom model class:

```
class AlertNotification {
    var title: String
    var message: String

    init(title: String, message: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.message = message
    }
}
```

In this way, only VC that overrides `shouldDisplayAlertNotification`will display alert.

**2. If you want to display alert on 'demand':**

As suggested, extend UIViewController

```
extension UIViewController {
    func showNotification(title: String, message: String) {
    }
}
```

Comment: This way, when i want to use viewDidAppear in my VC, it overrides GenericViewContoller's viewDidAppear. Isn't it?

Comment: Yep, but you can call super.viewDidAppear as first instruction, so alert will displayed

Answer (score 3):

Use an extension like this

```
extension UIViewController {
  func showAlert(title: String, message: String) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message:
      message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: {action in
    }))
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

call the function like this

```
self.showAlert(title: "hi", message: "test")
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can declare a simple method anywhere outside class.

```
func showAlertWithCompletion(message:String,okTitle:String,cancelTitle:String?,completionBlock:@escaping (_ okPressed:Bool)->()){
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: AppName, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: okTitle, style: .default) { (ok) in
        completionBlock(true)
    }
    alertController.addAction(okAction)
    if let cancelTitle = cancelTitle{
        let cancelOption = UIAlertAction(title: cancelTitle, style: .cancel, handler: { (axn) in
            completionBlock(false)

        })
        alertController.addAction(cancelOption)
    }

    if let topController = UIWindow.topViewController(){
      topController.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

This way wherever you call it, you will get ok button pressed callback in completion handle or even make Extension as described by @Ganesh Kumar

Answer (score 2):

Why not just an extension

```
extension UIViewController {

    func showNotification(title: String, message: String)
    {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "تائید", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this view controller extension to present alert view across the application.
https://github.com/SumitKr88/UIViewController-ShowAlertView/blob/master/UIViewController%2BExtensions.swift

```
extension UIViewController {

/// Show alert view
/// - Parameter title: title of alert
/// - Parameter message: message of alert
/// - Parameter actionTitles: List of action button titles(ex : "OK","Cancel" etc)
/// - Parameter style: Style of the buttons
/// - Parameter actions: actions repective to each actionTitles
/// - Parameter preferredActionIndex: Index of the button that need to be shown in bold. If nil is passed then it takes cancel as default button.

/**
 Example usage:-
 Just make sure actionTitles and actions array the same count.

 /********** 1. Pass nil if you don't need any action handler closure. **************/
 self.showAlert(title: "Title", message: "message", actionTitles: ["OK"], style: [.deafult], actions: [nil])

 /*********** 2. Alert view with one action **************/

 ///     let okActionHandler: ((UIAlertAction) -> Void) = {(action) in
 //Perform action of Ok here
 }
 self.showAlert(title: "Title", message: "message", actionTitles: ["OK", "CANCEL"], style: [.default, .cancel], actions: [okayActionHandler, nil])

 /********** 3.Alert view with two actions **************/

 let okActionHandler: ((UIAlertAction) -> Void) = {(action) in
 //Perform action of ok here
 }

 let cancelActionHandler: ((UIAlertAction) -> Void) = {(action) in
 //Perform action of cancel here
 }

 self.showAlert(title: "Title", message: "message", actionTitles: ["OK", "CANCEL"], style: [.default, .cancel], actions: [okActionHandler,cancelActionHandler], preferredActionIndex: 1)
 */

public func showAlert(title: String?,
                      message: String?,
                      actionTitles: [String?],
                      style: [UIAlertAction.Style],
                      actions: [((UIAlertAction) -> Void)?],
                      preferredActionIndex: Int? = nil) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    for (index, title) in actionTitles.enumerated() {
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: title, style: style[index], handler: actions[index])
        alert.addAction(action)
    }
    if let preferredActionIndex = preferredActionIndex { alert.preferredAction = alert.actions[preferredActionIndex] }
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create extension to alertController and also have option for action handler. This will allow to use two different Alert controller based on handler is required or not.

```
extension  UIAlertControler {

class func genericErrorAlert(forAlert message: String, completion: ((UIAlertAction) -> Void)? = nil )

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: completion))

    return alert
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create one util file in your app, in that you can add any reusable method or function and use it anywhere in your app Like,

import Foundation
import UIKit

//MARK: - ALERT

func showMessage(title: String, message: String!, VC: UIViewController) {

```
let alert : UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
    UIAlertAction in
}
alert.addAction(okAction)
VC.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

}